# Outlook Rule for subject line when words are ran together?

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server, rules

I have created a rule for a customer so that everytime the word "invoice" shows up in the subject line it gets sent to an "Invoices" folder. Well sometime the clients will send e-mails with a subject line such as "invoice/23242" and it will not filter that since invoice/23242 is run on. Is there a way for the rule to look for the word invoice no matter if its by it's self or if it has another character next to it without a space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That rule should work, I have just tested it on the word "time" knowing that i have an email reminding me to fill out my "timesheet" today and the rule ran and worked. I am using outlook 2013 with exchange server.

Make sure that the rule is for "invoice" not "invoice " (with a space at the end)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I tested this myself and noticed that it worked on my end as well. After further investigation it looks like there were mutliple rules that were conflicting with another ( The top said the more e-mail to folder based on e-mail address, the lower rule then said to move to invoices folder based on subject line) so the first rule was taking effect before the second rule could take effect.

Thanks!